# Best way to share sequalize models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a set of `sequalize` models that I'm using on my server but also want to share the same on a lambda deployment. It will likely be in a different repo. Is the easiest way to share between the two to make an npm package containing just the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely think that's the easiest - That's how we share models between backend, workers, etc.

The db package is published as a private repo, so only available with the right npm access token